# Conditional Probability with Population Proportion Given, Self Study

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

I'm taking a practice online stats exam to prepare for a real test coming up. 
The following question has me stumped:

Say we have a random sample of n = 15 online customers from a large population of customers to a popular online auction site. With p = 0.07 of the population proportion making a purchase, what is the probability of selecting exactly two customers who actually make a purchase in the random sample? Please round up to the fourth decimal point.

My logic is as follows:
This doesn't appear to be the case of how many marbles of a certain color are left in the bag type question.

Since it didn't appear to be an instance where n reducing would impact the p (as p is expressed as a constant rate), I have assumed the rate (p) would stay the same as n changes. Based on a comment there's a good chance that assumption is wrong.

If I do need to adjust p for a reduction in n, can someone help me with that equation?

What I've tried so far is the following:
The proportion is expressed as a constant so I decided to use the multiplication rule for independent events:

P(A and B) = P(A)P(B)

P(A and B) = .07 * .07

P(A and B) = 0.0049

And the auto-grading system tells me I'm getting wrong.

I'm getting stumped because the rule I applied seems to be only one that makes sense to me.  If someone can please help me understand where I'm going astray I would really appreciate it.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Your approach is not using $n$, which is a hint that something is missing. You have a series of $n=15$ experiments, each with a chance $p=0.07$ of success. You are looking for the probability of having exactly two successes. Does this reformulation suggest a way forward to you? (No, bags of marbles are a dead end.)

Comment: You do not provide enough indications on your background in probability and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @StephanKolassa updated question based on your comment.  Helpful.  I don't know equation to figure out how to account for n changing to 14.  Can you suggest formula to use/how to calculate?  Thank you!

Comment: As in Vlad's answer, I would next have encouraged you to read the opening paragraphs to [the Wikipedia page on the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). If I may be so bold: a question like this one should immediately suggest the binomial distribution to you, especially the way I recast it. Since you are preparing for an exam, I would suggest that you emphasize recognizing typical use cases for the standard distribution, and figuring out which distribution is appropriate where. Good luck!

Comment: @StephanKolassa, thank you for being bold - yes, this is my weakest section of the subject.  I took an online stats class that did not cover probability and now for another program it has an online practice exam with just a couple of probability questions on it and I'm scrambling to understand those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you have been asked can be reformulated in terms of Binomial Distribution:

Having done *n* (=15) independent experiments with success probability *p* (=0.07), what is the probability to get exactly *k* (=2) successes?

Then, if a random variable *X* follows Binomial Distribution, probability of getting exactly *k* successes in *n* independent trials is given by the probability mass function:

$$\Pr (X = k) = {n\choose k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$$

where ${n\choose k} = \frac{n!}{k! \cdot (n-k)!}$  is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Thank you for answering, +1. For [tag:self-study] questions, we typically try to provide hints so the OP has to do some work themselves, instead of full solutions - this helps them learn better. [See this meta thread.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5064/1352)

Comment: @StephanKolassa, sorry! I didn't know that! Will not happen again.

Comment: @StephanKolassa if this helps, this formula is already on my provided formula sheet approved to use during the actual exam -  I just did not know which formula to apply in this case.  I understand why normally this is frowned upon.